# jQuery prevent writing letters and change comma to dot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to modify this code but it just wont work...probably some small mistake but i can't debug it :(

```
// replace , with . and block writing letters
$(document).on("keydown", ".amount", function () {
      $(this).keydown(function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode==188 || e.keyCode==110 || e.keyCode==108){
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    $(this).val($(this).val() + '.');
                }
          var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
          return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || key == 110 || key == 188 || key == 190 || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));                
      });
};
```

[This is original code and it doesn't work on dynamic content](https://jsfiddle.net/r5n8xuhx/3/)
that is why i want to modify it!

Comment: what does `.amount` refer to? can you provide more information as to what you want to do? This line doesnt work `$(document).on("keydown", ".amount", function () {`

Comment: Note that your code is missing a closing `)` and the fiddle doesn't include the jQuery library

Comment: can you check this updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r5n8xuhx/3/   --that is what i want to achieve...but it doesn't work on dynamic content!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just calling your `ForceNumericOnly` method when the user clicks into an input with `.amount`?

```
$(document).on('focus', '.amount', function(){
    $(this).ForceNumericOnly();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/r5n8xuhx/5/

You could (should) optimise it so it doesn't add the `keydown` handler again if it's already run the `ForceNumericOnly` code... something like:

```
$.fn.ForceNumericOnly = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if($(this).data('forceNumberOnly'){ return; }
        $(this).data('forceNumberOnly',true);
        ...
    });
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/r5n8xuhx/6/

Comment: This is the answer to my question! Thank you Salomon!

Comment: Done - https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/r5n8xuhx/6/ . I've stuck an `alert()` in so you can see that the handler isn't executed multiple times for the same element.

Answer (score 0):

There's no JS required - just use a `number` input:

```html
<input class="amount" type="number">
```

Comment: and what about changing commas to a dot?

Comment: True, this just disallows the use of comma. However I would say that's a minor point when comparing the use of a native element to having to write a lot of code to handle commas.

Comment: I agree, this is a clever solution